# iframe loaded in Facebook page tab: signed_request returning 'profile_id' not 'page'

Tags: facebook

This is driving me crazy. I know a lot of people are having problems with empty signed_request parameters ... this not one of those questions!

I get the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] data and decode it in PHP without problem. I am using an iframe canvas to create a page tab, one of those 'click like to access more info' pages that are very popular at the moment.

The problem is the signed_request data does not contain a ['page'] field as expect, it contains a ['profile_id'] which is meant to be for "apps written in FBML and loaded in a Page tab" (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

I have checked and checked my settings, it's definitely an iframe canvas. Is anyone else having this problem?!

Example of decoded signed_request data:
`Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => 1320926195 [profile_id] => XXXXXXXXXX [user] => Array ( [country] => au [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by recreating the app. The old app was created a while ago when FBML was still an option, even though I'd changed the settings to iframe it was causing some legacy problem.

Anyway, nuking the app settings and starting again fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but creating another application wasn't an option to me. I started trying different configurations and I managed to start receiving the expected response when I activated the migration option **Page Tab iframe**

In your application Settings -> Advanced -> Page Tab iframe -> Enabled

You will then receive something like:

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","expires":0,"issued_at":1334321200,"oauth_token":"AAAAAZAj4rx20B4E3Z5BWYJwyfZATJFE9j0P3AXZAnEum451qFiIXnhCvzmZCFIZCmZCc83JKUsiyhzRSpFDXHEXzmeBIqjHdVxtWI1xNBSCPzwZDZD","page":{"id":"259117083013","liked":true,"admin":true},"user":{"country":"es","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}},"user_id":"342"}"
```